# What does jQuery .next method return if invoked on the already last element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a task to traverse from one particular row of the table to either another particular row or an end of the table. I am sure I can check the returned value of the `.next` method to check that the last processed node was the last sibling. What exactly does this method return in this situation? The documentation page about the method doesn't specify it or I can't find it.

Comment: an empty jQuery object....

Comment: ... which means an empty .length, which you can check for...

Comment: But why isn't it written anywhere? Did I look into a wrong place?

Comment: A jQuery object may be empty, containing no DOM elements. You can create an empty jQuery object with $() (that is, passing no arguments at all). A jQuery object may also be empty if a selector doesn't select any elements, or if a chained method filters out all the elements. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

Comment: I wasn't sure because `.next` doesn't pick a set of element but rather gets you one particular element. So can I be sure it returns a correct empty jQuery object and not throws any exceptions or generates warnings?

Comment: I still don't understand how could be obvious. Different functions act differently on failures, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if there a control next.

```
if($("myselector").next().length > 0)
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: i edited my answer to show you how to check if there a control next

Comment: @German The final next call in the example, contains the answer to your question.

Comment: Delete everything before that last call and I'll except your answer.